# Highlight active line in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Looking at the [demo](https://codemirror.net/demo/activeline.html) here, I downloaded the `active-line.js` file and included it in my HTML as shown in the demo but nothing happens. I included it like so:

```
<script src="/js/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="/js/sql.js"></script>
<script src="/js/active-line.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/codemirror.css">
```

This is how I initialise CodeMirror:

```
<script>
    CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("maple_code"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode: "text/x-mysql"
    });
</script>
```

Syntax highlighting and line numbers work as they should except the active line highlighting. Do I need to tweak anything in the options as well?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who builds their project with Webpack or other similar tools here is a **full** sequence of actions needed to highlight active lines:

1. Add the following import: `import 'codemirror/addon/selection/active-line';`
2. On CodeMirror instance creation specify `styleActiveLine` option:

   ```
   const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(
       textAreaElement, 
       {
           styleActiveLine: { nonEmpty: true }
           /* add other options here if you need */
       }
   )
   ```
3. From now CSS-class `.CodeMirror-activeline` will be automatically added to currently active line, at the same time `.CodeMirror-activeline-background` class will be also added to its child `div` that is responsible for background. The default background style should be applied automatically when you add `import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'`.

   If not, you may still need to write a background style manually. For example:

   ```
   .CodeMirror-activeline-background {
       background: #e8f2ff;
   }
   ```

   Or, if you would like to highlight active lines only when CodeMirror element is focused:

   ```
   .CodeMirror-focused .CodeMirror-activeline-background {
       background: #e8f2ff;
   }
   ```

   If the default style was applied, but you would like to turn it off when CodeMirror element is not focused:

   ```
   .CodeMirror:not(.CodeMirror-focused) .CodeMirror-activeline-background {
       background: unset;
   }
   ```
4. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do this.

Initialise your `CodeMirror` object like this:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("maple_code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    styleActiveSelected: true,
    mode: "text/x-mysql"
});
```

The line `styleActiveLine: true` is what you basically need. `styleActiveSelected: true` is optional and it makes it so active line styling persists when you select a line.

Comment: `styleActiveSelected: true` doesn't work. Instead you need to provide an object to `styleActiveLine`. I.e. `styleActiveLine: {nonEmpty: true}`.

Comment: Neither of these two (setting 'true' or ''{nonEmpty: true}') works for me with jupyterLab 2.1.5. In both cases the line is not highlighted.